# Trying to sort a struct array in Descending Order

Tags: c, algorithm, struct, operating-system, bubble-sort

To preface what I'm trying to do - I'm trying to make a Shortest Job First (SJF), the OS algo in C.

And to handle the sort-by-burst-time, I'm pushing all the ready processes in a stack, and then sorting that stack in a descending order. So for example - if the stack looks like 3,5,1,2 with "2" on top, I'm trying to sort it as: 5,3,2,1 with "1" on top. So when I start using pop, I'll get elements in the order I require.

But the problem with the code I'm going to show is, it orders 1,1,5,3 as 5,1,1,3. The last process "3" is never sorted.

Code for Sorting:

```
void sortByBurst() {
    int size = top;
    struct fcfs temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (size - 1 - i); j++) {
            if (stack[j].burst < stack[j + 1].burst) {
                temp = stack[j];
                stack[j] = stack[j + 1];
                stack[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in case you want to see where I'm handling the rest of the logic i.e making decisions on what to push - this is the for loop for that:

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfProc; i++) {
        if (first_process == 1 && p[i].arrival <= current_time && p[i].completed == 0) {
            min_index = i;
        } else if (first_process == 0 && last_index != -1) {
            for (int k = 0; k < numOfProc; k++) {
                if (p[k].completed == 0 && p[k].arrival <= p[last_index].max_slot && p[k].inQ != 1) {
                    push(p[k]);

                    p[k].inQ = 1;
                    critical_case = 1;
                } else if (p[k].completed == 0 && p[k].arrival > finalp[last_index].max_slot && p[k].inQ != 1) {
                    min_index = k;
                }
            }

            if (critical_case == 1) {
                sortByBurst();
                struct fcfs compare = pop();
                for (int l = 0; l < numOfProc; l++) {
                    if (compare.pid == p[l].pid) {
                        min_index = l;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    }
```

The input I'm testing my code with is:

```
 1. Process 1 | 2 (Arrival) | 1 (Burst)
 2. Process 2 | 1 (Arrival) | 5 (Burst)
 3. Process 3 | 4 (Arrival) | 1 (Burst)
 4. Process 4 | 0 (Arrival) | 6 (Burst)
 5. Process 5 | 2 (Arrival) | 3 (Burst)
```

Required Output:

```
 1. Process 4 | 0 (Arrival) | 6 (Burst)
 2. Process 1 | 2 (Arrival) | 1 (Burst)
 3. Process 3 | 4 (Arrival) | 1 (Burst)
 4. Process 5 | 2 (Arrival) | 3 (Burst)
 5. Process 2 | 1 (Arrival) | 5 (Burst)
```

Output I'm Getting:

```
 1. Process 4 | 0 (Arrival) | 6 (Burst)
 2. Process 5 | 2 (Arrival) | 3 (Burst)
 3. Process 3 | 4 (Arrival) | 1 (Burst)
 4. Process 1 | 2 (Arrival) | 1 (Burst)
 5. Process 2 | 1 (Arrival) | 5 (Burst)
```

As you can see, the Process 5 should be at 4th place in the list. But because in Stack - it's still on Top even after sorting, the algo is not working as it should. Kindly look into what I'm doing wrong here.

**Complete Code:**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fcfs {
    int pid, arrival, burst, min_slot, max_slot, wait_time, completed, inQ;
};

struct fcfs stack[10];
int top = -1;

void push(struct fcfs process);

struct fcfs pop();

void sortByBurst();

void pline(int x);

void main() {

    int i, numOfProc, j;
    int counter = 0;
    int current_time = 0;
    int completed = 0;
    struct fcfs p[10], finalp[10];
    int first_process = 1;
    int prevMaxSlot = 0;
    int last_index = -1;
    int critical_case = 0;

    printf("Enter total number of Processes \n");
    scanf("%d", &numOfProc);

    for (i = 0; i < numOfProc; i++) {
        printf("Enter Arrival Time & Burst Time for Process %d: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d %d", &p[i].arrival, &p[i].burst);
        p[i].pid = i + 1;
        p[i].wait_time = 0;
        p[i].completed = 0;
        p[i].inQ = 0;
    }

    int prev = 0;

    while (completed != numOfProc) {

        int min_index = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < numOfProc; i++) {
            if (first_process == 1 && p[i].arrival <= current_time && p[i].completed == 0) {
                min_index = i;
            } else if (first_process == 0 && last_index != -1) {
                for (int k = 0; k < numOfProc; k++) {
                    if (p[k].completed == 0 && p[k].arrival <= p[last_index].max_slot && p[k].inQ != 1) {
                        push(p[k]);

                        p[k].inQ = 1;
                        critical_case = 1;
                    } else if (p[k].completed == 0 && p[k].arrival > finalp[last_index].max_slot && p[k].inQ != 1) {
                        min_index = k;
                    }
                }

                if (critical_case == 1) {
                    sortByBurst();
                    struct fcfs compare = pop();
                    for (int l = 0; l < numOfProc; l++) {
                        if (compare.pid == p[l].pid) {
                            min_index = l;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        if (min_index == -1) {
            current_time++;
        } else {
            if (p[min_index].arrival == prevMaxSlot) {
                p[min_index].min_slot = prevMaxSlot;
                p[min_index].max_slot = p[min_index].arrival + p[min_index].burst;
            } else if (p[min_index].arrival < prevMaxSlot || p[min_index].arrival == prevMaxSlot) {
                p[min_index].min_slot = prevMaxSlot;
                p[min_index].max_slot = p[min_index].min_slot + p[min_index].burst;
            } else if (p[min_index].arrival > prevMaxSlot) {
                p[min_index].min_slot = p[min_index].arrival;
                p[min_index].max_slot = p[min_index].arrival + p[min_index].burst;
            }
            p[min_index].wait_time = (first_process == 1) ? 0 : abs(p[i].min_slot - prev);
            p[min_index].completed = 1;
            prev = current_time;
            prevMaxSlot = p[min_index].max_slot;


            finalp[counter++] = p[min_index];
            first_process = 0;
            last_index = min_index;
            completed++;


        }

    }


    pline(44);
    printf("Slot\tPID\tArrival\t\tBurst\n");
    pline(44);


    for (i = 0; i < numOfProc; i++) {
        if ((finalp[i].min_slot - finalp[i - 1].max_slot) > 0 && i > 0) {
            printf("%d - %d\tNONE\tNONE\t\tNONE\n", finalp[i - 1].max_slot, finalp[i].min_slot);
        } else if ((abs(0 - finalp[i].min_slot) > 0 && i == 0)) {
            printf("0 - %d\tNONE\tNONE\t\tNONE\n", finalp[i].min_slot);
        }

        printf("%d - %d\t%d\t%d\t\t%d\n", finalp[i].min_slot, finalp[i].max_slot, finalp[i].pid, finalp[i].arrival,
               finalp[i].burst);
    }
    pline(44);

}


void pline(int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void push(struct fcfs process) {
    if (top == 10)
        printf("\n Overflow");
    else {
        top = top + 1;
        stack[top] = process;
    }
}


struct fcfs pop() {
    struct fcfs process;
    if (top == -1)
        printf("Underflow");
    else {
        process = stack[top];
        top = top - 1;
    }

    return process;

}

void sortByBurst() {
    int size = top + 1;
    struct fcfs temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (size - 1 - i); j++) {
            if (stack[j].burst < stack[j + 1].burst) {
                temp = stack[j];
                stack[j] = stack[j + 1];
                stack[j + 1] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort) you should repeat the outer loop in bubble sort until not further swaps occur in the inner loop.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please elaborate what you mean with code?

Comment: bubble-sort can be (and all too often is) implemented without no-swap-early-exit, the optimization that delivers best-case O(n) performance to which Axel is referring. However, isolating just the sorting algorithm and testing it solo, it is functionally correct, and will sort as expected. It's bubble sort, so that ain't saying much, [but it is nonetheless functionally sound](https://godbolt.org/z/xPMs6Y758). The problem isn't your sort from what I can see.

Comment: What else could it be? By the time the compiler moves to the sorting function, the stack is ready and set to be sorted. I've been at it for 8 hours now, trying different solutions around it - nothing seems to be giving me the results I need.

Comment: You clearly have a mountain of code *besides* that trivial bubblesort algorithm, nearly all of which we're *not* privy to. I cannot tell you what it is; I can only tell you that bubblesort implementation looks correct.

Comment: Is `top` supposed to be one-past-the-end, or is it the actual index of the last element?  That makes a big difference, because your loops are treating it as if it's one-past-the-end, but the output you say you're getting suggests that it's not. https://godbolt.org/z/h5xGcb4ff -- in short, perhaps `int size = top + 1;` will fix your problem.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (which was a valid one) - but it still doesn't seem to fix it. I've updated the main post with the complete code, if possible - you can observe it in detail and see if top is still the issue. Thank you btw

Comment: You've corrected the `top`/`size` bug now, but in the new code you've posted, you start with `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`.

Comment: Ah. finally lol. Thanks a lot - that does fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with top &  i = 1;

In the sorting function, `int size = top + 1` and initializing the for loop with `i = 0` fixed it.

Thanks a lot to all who contributed.

Comment: Or, you could have kept  `int size = top` and avoid to subtract `1` from it in your `for` statements - which seems more readable imho